# Cakephp theme and images

Tags: php, image, cakephp, themes, cakephp-2.0

I have a weird problem in CakePHP.

I use a theme so I have a folder Themed/mytheme and in this case I have `Themed/mytheme/webroot/img/`

And my concern is that, in this file picture I have several images. Until now all my images are displayed in the url `/theme/mytheme/img/myimage.png`.

And this morning I created another image so I saved in this folder img and there problem. When I want to display my image I get the following error:

```
missing Controller
Error: ThemeController could not be found.

Error: Create the class below in ThemeController file: app \ Controller \ ThemeController.php

<? php
ThemeController class extends AppController {

}
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app \ View \ Errors \ missing_controller.ctp

Stack Trace
APP \ webroot \ index.php line 92 → Dispatcher-> dispatch (CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

I error is not with the rest of the images is in the same folder.

Can you tell me or it could come from please?

Thank you.

P.S: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

### There's a typo in the url

Cake's default mod rewrite rules are:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This means if the url does *not* match a directory and does *not* match a file - send the request to CakePHP. Since your request is being handled by CakePHP - the path you've requested is not the same as the file you've created.

### Don't hardcode theme paths

To get an error like this, it seems quite likely to have code like this in view files:

```
echo $this->Html->image('/theme/ThemeName/img/foo.png');
```

That's not necessary and doing so will cause problems - like getting the path wrong, and requesting files that don't exist. Instead just use:

```
echo $this->Html->image('foo.png');
```

If the current request is for a theme - Cake will *automatically* use `/theme/ThemeName/img/foo.png` if it exists, and `/img/foo.png` if not.